# Report Application Server Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to enter a value to the parameter in crystal report that does not match its edit mask. It throws a Report Application server failed error. Is there anyway to catch this exception and throw a user understandable exception. The problem is that the stack trace does not show any part of my code.By the way my code is written in .net

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The Report Application Server failed
        at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.GetParamPromptingInfo(PromptingRequestInfo promptingRequestInfo, Object& promptingUnits, Object& promptingInfoProvider) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.DoParameterPrompting(PromptingRequestContext reqContext) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.ReportAgent+ReportClosedExceptionHandlingReportSource.DoParameterPrompting(PromptingRequestContext reqContext) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.ReportAgentBase.DoPrompting(PromptingHTMLRenderOption htmlOption) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.Components.ParamComponent.ShowFullPrompt() : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.Components.ParamComponentBase.HandleException(Exception e) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.HandleExceptionAndPromptIfNeeded(Exception x, EnumAspNetLifeCycleStage stage) : Line 0
        at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) : Line 0
        at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() : Line 0
        at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() : Line 0
        at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() : Line 0
        at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) : Line 0
```

Comment: You can try pressing Ctrl + Alt + E to open the Exceptions window, then checking the box for Common Language Runtime Exceptions. This will hopefully narrow down _where_ this exception is getting thrown in your code.

Comment: How are you displaying the report in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net ReportViewer has `ReportError` event which u can handle and customize the error `OnReportError="ReportViewer1_OnReportError"`

Check CrystalReportViewer whether it has something like that:

```
CrystalReportViewer.onHandleException or
CrystalReportViewer.OnHandleExceptionAndPromptIfNeeded

HandleException()   Fired when an exception occurs.
```

ref: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_Net_Ch14_3.asp
not easy to find a fresh documentation for that.